# How to seprate RGB planes as three different gray scale images?

Tags: image, matlab, rgb

I want to seprate RGB planes of a color image as three gray scale image in MATLAB. But they are colored. How can I do it? I use the below code:

```
red    = I(:,:,1); % Red channel
green  = I(:,:,2); % Green channel
```

Comment: How are they colored? Did you try `imshow(I(:,:,1))`?

Comment: You might need to set `colormap('gray')` if it's showing with a different colormap.

Comment: i used image() to show channels and they are colored..sorry i am new in matlab and i did not know the difference between them now i use imshow() and it is gray scale.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `image` will show the matrix as an image with the default colour map of whatever version of MATLAB you are using.  For version R2014b and higher, it will show this in the parula colour map and other versions show this in the jet colour map.  If you wish to visualize this as a grayscale image, you must use `colormap gray;` after you call `image`.

However, if you have the Image Processing Toolbox, you can simply use `imshow` and single channel images default to showing the contents as grayscale.